# Crashing on Plants vs Zombies for PS3

Tags: ps3, plants-vs-zombies

I'm experiencing lots of issues with PvZ on PS3:

- The game crashes whenever I enter the Zen Garden (but this worked before)
- The game greatly slows down on Survival Endless
- It regularly freezes in-game for about 10-15 seconds
- The music is pretty messed-up, you can hear more than 2 background music playing simultaneously.

Has anyone else experienced these issues?
How can I report these issues? On PC, I just post it on Steam and there are support provided there but how on PS3 version of this game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Their site](http://www.popcap.com/help7.php?icid=help_console) links to the [Sony site](http://www.us.playstation.com/Support) for support. You should then give it a try.
In the meantime, try perhaps uninstalling and reinstalling the game if not already done.